# receive error in magento 1.9 data export

Tags: php, magento

I received an error when trying to export product data in Magento 1.9. It said **"no valid data sent"**. Based on other posts, I was able to locate my `system.log' (in var/log folder & changed permissions to 777). It looks like there are several errors and i'm not sure when they occurred or which to look at. The last one, which seems relevant, is:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 331  in includes/src/Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Product.php on line 875.

I read that `331 = Product ID`. But, when I go to manage products, there is no product ID of 331. I may have added it a few weeks ago when I was testing uploads, but I've since deleted it. So, I'm not sure what to do there.

I also tried to locate the file mentioned in the error, but it wasn't in that file path. I ended up going to:

> app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity.

(I assume that is the right file to review). `The code on line 873-5` is:

```
} else {    
$dataRow[self::COL_STORE] = null;
$dataRow += $stockItemRows[$productId];
```

Any advice on next steps?
Your help is greatly appreciated!

Please note: I also checked my exceptions.log and it doesn't look as if anything has been added to the file since Aug 11.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and format the code as code. For blocks of code, indent with 4 spaces at the start of each line. For inline code use the grave symbol that you can find in the help topic. Error message are sometimes more easily read when formatted as code also.

Comment: If you may have deleted the product previously I would begin by clearing the Magento cache and forcing a reindex of all of the Magento indices. You can find this at System->Index Management in the system admin menu.

If the indexes are stale it may be that Export model is looking for the product from the index data and it no longer exists.

Comment: are there more errors in `system/log` system.log ? have checked exception log? what in that?

Comment: hope that's better @JeffC

Comment: I  flushed cache storage, the magento cache, and reindexed all of the indices that were listed, but I'm still getting an error @andyredfern

Comment: There are thousands of lines in the system.log (although there is repetition), so I'm not sure what to look at. The last things registered are related to this line:                                                                                            
Warning: simplexml_load_string():    ^  in /includes/src/__default.php on line 22966 @urfusion

Comment: delete all lines and run again then check the errors.

Comment: There are hundreds of mentions similar to this: Notice: Undefined offset: 0  in /includes/src/Cmsmart_Megamenu_Block_Navigation.php on line 295. Some point to undefined variables in this file and various lines to check. The warnings that I posted previously also appear.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your permissions are wrong. Run the following commands under SSH within the same directory as your Magento installation.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 550 pear
chmod 550 mage #for magento 1.5+
```

I also smell compilation all over this.

Disable Compilation from Magento Admin Panel.

```
[System -> Tools -> Compilation -> Disable]
```

Also clear all Core/Storage cache via SSH. Run the following commands,

```
cd <your-magento-installation-directory>/var/cache/
rm -rf *
```

Retry your data export again.

Comment: I followed all of the steps above, but it still didn't work. Note, I got an error during ssh **the pear directory doesn't exist**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving back changing the code on line 875:

```
} else {
$dataRow[self::COL_STORE] = null;
if ($productId < 331 and $productId  > 333)  $dataRow += $stockItemRows[$productId];
```